# Standalone Smartwatch App with Cordova

Tags: cordova, wear-os, apple-watch, sony-smartwatch

are there plans in cordova to support standalone apps for smartwatches? Or are they any examples how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using those given in GitHub, [Cordova Android Wear Plugin](https://github.com/tgardner/cordova-androidwear) and [example](https://github.com/tgardner/cordova-androidwear-example)?

Comment: Thank's for sharing. But my intention is to create a hybrid standalone app on a smart watch. And I ask myself if I add android/apple as platform or if there are special plans to provide a new platform for wear/watch.